# Prevent Default for Ajax created form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, live, form-submit

I am getting the form on click from a file called `test.php` which contains the following:

```
<form method="post" class="adminTM">
    <input type="hidden" name="execID" value="<?=$_POST['exec']?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="fromTM" value="<?=$_POST['TM']?>" />
    <input type="text" name="toTM" value="<?=$_POST['TM']?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="symbol" value="<?=$_POST['symbol']?>" />
    <button class="submitTM">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

The javascript looks like so:

```
$(function(){

    $('.adminTMClick').live('click', function(e){
        $(this).data('TM', this.innerHTML);
        $.post('test.php', $(this).data(), function(data){
            $(data).dialog({
                modal: true,
                beforeClose: function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
            console.log($('.adminTM'));
            console.log($('.submitTM'));
        });
    });

    $('.submitTM').live('click', function(e){ 
        //originally had .adminTM with submit which failed
        e.preventdefault();
        alert('i am here');
        return false;
    });

});
```

How do i make it so that the form **DOES NOT** do the default submit action when the submit button is clicked?

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates basically what I am doing (i had to change it a bit because of the way jsfiddle works): http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/tQVnV/show/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `submit()` event on the form instead of the `click()` on the submit, since pressing enter will still submit the form (bypassing the submit button).

This should properly prevent the form from doing the default submit:

```
$('.adminTM').live('submit', function(e) {
    // execute custom code
    console.log("submit event fired");

    // prevent default submit
    return false;
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjorn/tQVnV/11/

Comment: Apologies, it's late here. I'm curious whate exactly failed by using `.submit()` though, I've used this in the past without issues.

Comment: This seems to be working fine here, could you test this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjorn/tQVnV/11/show

Comment: odd that I tryed that before and it wasnt working, and now it works fine. thank you!   Can you add that fiddle as an update to ur original answer?

Comment: Will do, I'll also edit the code so it's using `.live('submit')`, glad I could help.

Comment: add the fiddle for future users.

Comment: `preventDefault` is far more appropriate than `return false`. Unfortunately, it's also a _pain in the ass_.